# Shorthand for extracting a high-dimensional sub-array, i.e. array[beg[0]:end[0],beg[1]:end[1],...]

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for a concise way of extracting a subarray from a high-dimensional array.

For example let's take an array `a`. I want to extract a subarray, for which I have the beginning and end coordinates stored in two arrays `b` and `e`.

Currently, to extract the desired subarray, I type

```
a[b[0]:e[0],b[1]:e[1],b[2]:e[2],b[3]:e[3],...]
```

I was wondering if there is a built-in, concise way of slicing such an array. I would love calling something like `a[b:e]`, but this does not work.

Comment: No builtin, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47605511/7207392).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` the two arrays and construct a tuple of slice objects from the resulting tuples from `zip`:

```
from itertools import starmap

a[tuple(starmap(slice, zip(b, e)))]
```

Comment: And if the indices are stored in a `(d, 2)` `np.array` to begin with, one can get rid of the `zip` and obtain a slightly more concise `a[tuple(startmap(slice, ind))]`

Answer (score 0):

If the subclassing `np.s_` approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47605511/7207392) is too heavy for your liking, you can use:

```
a[tuple(slice(*idx) for idx in np.broadcast(start, stop, step))]
```

The beauty of using `np.broadcast` here is that you can for example mix scalars and lists as in start=None, stop=[1,2,3]. This would be equivalent to `a[:1, :2, :3]`.