# Multi dimensional array slice in one object

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I have a numpy array:

```
arr = numpy.arange(25 * 10 * 20)
arr.resize((25, 10, 20))
```

I want to get slice like this:

```
arr[3:6, 2:8, 7:9]
```

This works:

```
index = [slice(3, 6), slice(2, 8), slice(7, 9)]
arr[index]
```

But this doesn't:

```
>>> index = slice([3, 2, 7], [6, 8, 9])
>>> arr[index]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Can it be done by ONE `slice` object? Or only `list` of 3 `slice`s will work?

Comment: Not out of the box and not as one slice but [this class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47605511/7207392) makes it almost as convenient.

Comment: Given the current definition of `slice` and `numpy` indexing, a tuple of slices is the base object.  Any alternative will end up producing that.

Comment: By the way, a tuple is an object.  And a slice is a simple class as well, with three attributes  and few methods.  It's .__getitem__ that does the work.

Comment: @Śmigło, what version of NumPy are you using? Your "This works:" example gives me an IndexError in v1.23.2.

Comment: Me to - seems not to work any longer. Anyone knows how to do that correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> help(slice)
class slice(object)
 |  slice(stop)
 |  slice(start, stop[, step])
```

So we use slice(start, stop, step)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(10)

## ERROR

>>> i=slice([1,3])
>>> x[i]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

## OK

>>> i = slice(3,7,2)
>>> print(x)
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
>>> print(i)
slice(3, 7, 2)
>>> print(x[i])
[3 5]
```

For multi dimensional:

```
>>> x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
>>> x
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> i = slice(0,3,1)
>>> i
slice(0, 2, 1)
>>> x[i,i]
array([[0, 1],
       [4, 5]])
```

Comment: Nice clear examples but I don't think this answers OP's question. I believe OP is looking for a way to use a single object to specify an arbitrary multidimensional slice, as in `x[foo]`, which is more general than the `x[i,i]` case you present here.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of slices, zipping the two lists of indices:

```
>>> slices = [slice(*i) for i in zip([3,2,7], [6,8,9])]
>>> arr[slices]
array([[[ 647,  648],
    [ 667,  668],
    [ 687,  688],
    [ 707,  708],
    [ 727,  728],
    [ 747,  748]],

   [[ 847,  848],
    [ 867,  868],
    [ 887,  888],
    [ 907,  908],
    [ 927,  928],
    [ 947,  948]],

   [[1047, 1048],
    [1067, 1068],
    [1087, 1088],
    [1107, 1108],
    [1127, 1128],
    [1147, 1148]]])
```

Check with `numpy.array_equal`:

```
>>> numpy.array_equal(arr[slices], arr[3:6,2:8,7:9])
True
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`numpy.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html):

```
  a[ogrid[3:6, 2:8, 7:9]]
```

select you block.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working in v1.23.2—getting an IndexError.

Answer (score 1):

> Can it be done by ONE slice object?

No, slice objects are one-dimensional.

> Or only list of 3 slices will work?

A *list* of 3 slices will not work as of v1.23.0. Multidimensional indexing with non-tuple values has been deprecated since v1.15 and expired in v1.23.0 (see this [section of the changelog](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.23.0-notes.html#expired-deprecations)).

As of v1.23.0, the only way to specify a multidimensional slice with a single object is to use a tuple of slice objects. If you would like to use `[:]` notation, you can create a tuple of slice objects using [`numpy.s_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html). In OP's case:

```py
>>> numpy.s_[3:6, 2:8, 7:9]
(slice(3, 6, None), slice(2, 8, None), slice(7, 9, None))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `np.s_`, "A nicer way to build up index tuples for arrays", what you want ?

```
A = np.arange( 25 * 10 * 20 ).reshape( 25, 10, 20 )

region = np.s_[ 3:6, 2:8, 7:9 ]
# (slice(3, 6, None), slice(2, 8, None), slice(7, 9, None))

A[region]  # your arr[slices], shape (3, 6, 2)
```

(would be nice if the [doc for np.s_](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html) had such an example, not just 1d.)