# Numpy: how to make parameterized slice?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have this:

```
slice = ar[starts[0] : ends[0], starts[1] : ends[1], starts[2] : ends[2]]
```

How to make something like this:

```
slice = ar[starts[i] : ends[i] for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47605511/7207392) is a convenience object allowing you to write this as `sliced = ar[bs_[starts:ends]]` `bs_` stands for "block slice".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use `slice` as a variable name, as it is a builtin.

Second, what you are looking for uses that builtin:

```
ar[tuple(slice(s, e) for s, e in zip(starts, ends))]
```